# Is it possible to make a 3d circular scale in mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing

I want to make a 3d circular scale  with 100 divisions (marked from 0 to 100) in it. I think it is possible by making divisions over the outer surface of a 3d cylinder. [image]

Comment: Do you mean to generate the tick marks from 0..99 in 3D in a cylindrical arrangement?  You can use `Table` to create a list of `Line` primitives. If you don't know how to work with `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`, read [this short tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html). It's really easy: just construct a list of graphics primitives (like `Line`) and wrap them with `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 15):

You can get this effect by building the "label" for the cylinder using `Graphics` objects, and then "wrapping" it around a 3D parametric plot of a cylinder using `Texture`:

```
label = Graphics[
           Join[Table[Line[{{0, 99 - i}, {If[Mod[i, 10] == 0, 6, If[Mod[i, 5] == 0, 4, 3]], 99 - i}}], {i, 0, 99}], 
                Table[Text[ToString[i], {8, 99 - i}, {-1, 0}], {i, 0, 90, 10}]]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[th], Sin[th], -z}, {z, 0, 1}, {th, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[label], Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If it is desired that the cylinder have end-caps, this can be accomplished by combining this with other `ParametricPlot3D` or `Graphics3D` objects.